# django admin override css for inline model

Tags: css, django, admin

I'm using https://github.com/s-block/django-nested-inline with something like this:

```
class C(NestedStackedInline):
    model = C
    max_num = 1
    fk_name = 'B'

    class Media:
        css = {
             'all': ('/static/admin/css/forms-nested.css',)
        }


class B(NestedStackedInline):
    model = B

    class Media:
        css = {
             'all': ('/static/admin/css/forms-nested2.css',)
        }

    inlines = [C]


class A(NestedModelAdmin):
    model = A
    inlines = [B]
```

forms-nested.css is:

```
.inline-related h3 {
    margin: 0;
    color: #666;
    padding: 3px 5px;
    font-size: 11px;
    background: #e1e1e1 url(../img/nav-bg.gif) top left repeat-x;
    border-bottom: 1px solid #ddd;
}
```

and forms-nested2.css is:

```
.inline-related h3 {
    margin: 0;
    color: #484846;
    padding: 3px 5px;
    font-size: 11px;
    background: #D9DBCB;
    border-bottom: 1px solid #ddd;
}
```

Essentially I'm trying to have model-specific CSS for nested inlines. I want class C (the 2nd level inline) to have different h3 styling to class B (the 1st level inline). However class C's Media seems to override class B.

Is there any way to do this ?

Thanks

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It's not like `C`'s media is overriding `B`'s media. They both appear in your admin page, but...

CSS of `C`'s media is overriting CSS of `B`'s media. Because this is how CSS works. Try to change `forms-nested.css` to have this:

```
.inline-related .inline-related h3 {
```

That will only style nested `.inline-related h3`.